# mysql: find nearest date in table if within 30 days and echo out column name where result found?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a MySQL query that searches my table supplier_insurance and looks for the nearest date to today's date if within 30 days and if a result is found then I want to echo out the name of the column where the result was found.

So my table looks like this:

```
ID    |   User_ID   |   Public Insurance   |   Employer's Insurance 
1         1234          21-02-2015             02-12-2015
```

So in this example Public Insurance will be echoed out because it is the nearest date to today's date and it's within 30 days. Employer's Inusrance will not be echoed out because it is beyond 30 days.

I am hoping I can echo out the column name and number of days until the date.

So:

```
Public Insurance Expires in: 7 days.
```

Also, if there are 2 dates or more within 30 days then I want these to be echoed out aswell.

So let's say both Public Insurance expires on 21-02-2015 and Employer's Insurance expires on 22-02-2015.

Then both Public Insurance and Employer's Insurance would be echoed out with the number of days until the date is reached like so:

```
Public & Employer's Insurance expire within 8 days.
```

Is this possible?

so far I am having to query each date separate but I would rather not do it this way if there is an easier way.

```
   <?php
$info = "SELECT * FROM supplier_insurance WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'";
$result21 = mysql_query($info);
while ($row21 = mysql_fetch_array($result21)) {


$date = $row21['pub_insurance_end_date'];

$today = new DateTime(); // Today's Date/Time
$math = new DateTime($date);
$calc = $today->diff($math);
$count = $calc->format('%d days');


if (strtotime($date) <= strtotime('+30 days')) {
echo '<div class="panel_box">Public Liability Insurance Expires in '.$count.'</div>';
}else{
echo '<div class="panel_box">Insurance Up to Date.</div>';    
}




}
?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with a `union all` query.  In practice, you should just query for the dates that are within 30 days and use the application code to format strings.  But you *can* do that in the database if you want:

```
select concat('Public Insurance expires in ',
              datediff(now(), PublicInsurance),
              ' days')
from table t
where PublicInsurance >= date_sub(now(), interval 30 days)
union all
select concat('Employers Insurance expires in ',
              datediff(now(), EmployersInsurance),
              ' days')
from table t
where EmployersInsurance >= date_sub(now(), interval 30 days)
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried adding this to my MySQL statement but how would I echo out the results?